# PHP - How deep should I break out of the loops?

Tags: php, loops, switch-statement, break

I have infinite loop in PHP and need to know the integer after the break in the switch case. Right now I use `break 5;` but I am now sure if this is right. Could someone tells me how to break out of all of the loops but `while (true)`. I removed the unnecessary code so only the loops are left.

```
$i = 0;
while (true)
{
    // After the break 5 in the switch we should land here again

    foreach ($users as $user)
    {
        while ($i < 10)
        {
            if (!empty($user))
            {
                if (isset($user->id))
                {
                    switch($user->id)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            break 5;
                        default:
                            break 5; // Need to break out the foreach. So a break five right?
                    }
                }
            }

            $i++;
        }
    }

    $i=0;
}
```

Comment: why not test it? you can trivially set up some nested loops, and put some output after each so you can see where the break took to you.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php Probably `continue 3;`

Comment: Having such deeply indented code is generally quite difficult to understand and deal with. Why don't you flatten your if statements? If you put all your if statements at the same level and just say `$i++; continue;` if they are false, then you won't have so many nested statements and it will work the same.

Comment: You could also limit the `$users` array to 10 elements making the `while($...` unnecessary as well to help clean things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is 3, as break ends execution of the current for, foreach, while, do-while or switch structure.

Where `break 1` only exists the `switch`, *2* the `while` and *3* the `foreach` and *4* the main `while`.

But perhaps this is a better method, as you specifically state where to go instead of guessing. You cannot place the goto marker inside a loop, but in your case you can just make it before the loop.

```
$i = 0;
mybegin:
while (true){
    # 1. After the break 3 in the switch we will -not- land here.
    # 3. So if you want to start here, you will need to use the goto statement.

    foreach ($users as $user){
        while ($i < 10){
            if (!empty($user)){
                if (isset($user->id)){
                    switch($user->id){
                        case 1:
                            break 3;
                        default:
                            goto mybegin;
                    }
                }
            }

            $i++;
        }
    }
    # 2. Using break 3, the code continues here.
    $i=0;
}
```

But I have to say that I never needed that many loops or a goto statement for that matter as there is always a better way.

Comment: This is the answer with details and a nice explenation. Thank you so much, now I know I have to use break 3!